# Find all positive integer solutions for M

Tags: number-theory

Find all positive integer solutions M, where $x,y,z$ are non-negative integers from the equations,

$x + y + z = 94$

$4x + 10y + 19z = M$

Attempt:

I multiplied equation 1 by 4, and subtracted it from equation 2 to get

$6y + 15z = M-376$

I know $M-376$ has to be a multiple of 3, and $376 \le M \le 1786$ if we set $(y,x)$ to be $(0,0)$ and $(0,94)$ respectively, but I don't know what to incorporate next. Any clues?

Comment: So, we have to find the possible positive integer values of $4x+10y+19z$ given $x+y+z=94$ with non-negative integers $x,y,z$ , right ?

Comment: Yes, I should have put that in

Comment: y and z can now be anything so long as y + z < = 94.  6y + 15z may be any multiple of 3 that is greater then 12. Up to well... you can work that out so M = 376, 382,388, any 388+ 3k up to...

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be the set of all combinations of the form $2y+5z$ such that $y$ and $z$ are non-negative integers with $y+z\leq 94$.

You want the set $3S+376$.

So we just need to determine $S$.

We shall prove that $S$ contains every integer in the range $\{1,2,\dots , 94\times 5\}$ except a select few.

Which numbers that are congruent to $1\bmod 5$ can be made? the smallest is clearly $6$ while the largest is clearly $6+ 91\times 5$ ( so we are missing $1,93\times5+1$).

Which numbers that are congruent to $2\bmod 5$ can be made? the smallest is clearly $2$ and the largest is $2+93\times 5$ (so none is missing).

Which numbers that are $3\bmod 5$ can be made? the smallest is clearly $8$ while the largest is $8+90\times 5$ (so we are missing $3,92\times 5+3,93\times 5+3$

Which number that are $4\bmod 5$ can be made? The smallest is clearly $4$ and the largest is $4+92\times 5$ (so we are missing $93\times 5+4$).

Also, it is clear that all of the numbers in between each residue class can also be made, it is also clear that all multiples of $5$ can be made.

Therefore $S=\{1,2,3\dots , 94\times 5\} \setminus \{1,3,92\times 5+3,93\times5+1,93\times 5 +3,93\times 5 + 4\}$

Comment: What was the motivation behind choosing mod 5?

Comment: notice that $5$ is the larger of the two numbers (we are considering the sums of the form $2y+5z$). So for terms of maximizing or minimizing the sum with respect to $y+z\leq 94$ the term involving $5$ is more important). Also, that it works.